# Remove all files but one with rm

Tags: command-line, rm

Is there any way to remove all of the files in a directory *except* for one with a certain filename? For instance, if I had a directory containing the files `file1`, `file2`, and `dontdelete`. Would there be any way to quickly delete `file1`, and `file2` and not `dontdelete`? I know that I could just do `rm file1 file2` but that wouldn't work for a bunch of files. Also, I'm on Mac OS X if that makes a difference.

Comment: Simple wildcarding may be your solution: rm file* will remove file1 and file2 but not dontdelete. If your needs are more complex then, depending shell scripting language, you could generate a list of files you want to delete using a regular expression and pipe this to the rm command.

Comment: @Rob: Yeah, my situation is more complex than that. And Ignacio's answer worked. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(dontdelete)
```

Comment: +1 Wow very succinct solution. Will bear that in mind if I need it.

Comment: can this be extended to include multiple directories that you don't wan to delete