# Remove everything except?

Tags: rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove all files but one with rm](https://superuser.com/questions/227865/remove-all-files-but-one-with-rm)

In unix, to remove zip files in a directory one can simply type

```
rm *.zip
```

How can one remove everything except zip files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rm !(*.zip)
```

This appears to work. The ! represents "not".

extglob needs to be enabled in the shell behavior settings for this to work. It is probably already enabled... but if not, enable it with:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

And after answering this... indeed Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams you are correct. It is pretty much duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for adding the mention of `extglob`! I was able to run this command in the normal interactive prompt without a hitch, but then when trying something like `echo !(*.zip)` in a script, I would always get a syntax error. Adding that option fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a list then removing the file from the list.

Ex.

> ls $yourDir | grep -v .zip >
>   deleteThis.list

the call

> xargs rm < deleteThis.list

Comment: Why not just `rm $(ls | grep -v *.zip)` ? :)

Comment: There's that too! :)

Comment: @JohnT I know you posted that answer more than six years ago, but it helped me today. Thank you!!!