# Remove files that don't end on ".py" using rm 

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove all files but one with rm](https://superuser.com/questions/227865/remove-all-files-but-one-with-rm)

This is a very simple question and i dont know whether a solution exists or not.

I have some files in a directory, assume i have .py and some other extension files. now i would like to remove all files except those that end in `.py` files. How could i do that with the `rm` command?

That is i want something like

```
!(rm *.py)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(*.py)
```

You enable the extglob variable. This gives you some extra pattern matching features, particularly negation.

You can disable it again with `shopt -u extglob`.

Answer (score 5):

Easy to remember is find:

```
find -not -name "*.py" -delete
```

It will delete files in subdirs too, compared to the larsmas solution, but you can prevent that with the -maxdepth parameter.

Not every `find` implementation might support the `delete` option. Gnu find does since version 4.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv !(*.py) some_dir
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ls | grep -v ".py$" | xargs rm
```

Comment: Using `ls` for anything but human readable output is generally a bad idea. And parsing it is even worse. Use `find` instead.