# Remove all except one file and directory at path

Tags: grep, rm, xargs, multiple-instances

I need to remove all the files in a directory except for one file and one folder. Up to the grep I can output the correct list of items I want to remove but when i add xags, nothing is deleted.

this is the command I'm using.

```
ls domain.com/wp-content/themes | grep -v -E 'twentyeleven|index.php'  | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: [Remove all files but one with rm](http://superuser.com/q/227865/63893)

Comment: Thank you but that thread does not do exactly as I need, or at least does not go in detail on how to : keep multiple files, keep both files and directories, specify a directory path.

Comment: For multiple files, maybe this: shopt -s extglob; rm !(twentyeleven|index\.php)

Answer (score 0):

you could solve this with  some more diagnosis,

the command does work in practice, on a simple example.

So all you have to do is a bit of troubleshooting.

It looks like you have done troubleshooting to the point of finding 
ls domain.com/wp-content/themes | grep -v -E 'twentyeleven|index.php'
looks good.

Try ls file1 file2 file3  from within that directory.  | rm -rf

Try echo file1 file2 file3 | rm -rf

Try another directory, maybe there's some issue with that. Basic troubleshooting will take you much further possibly to the solution.

Here is an example that works. Tested in cygwin.

```
user@iar ~/aa
$ ls | grep -v -E "op"
er
qw
ty
ui

user@iar ~/aa
$ ls | grep -v -E "op" | xargs rm -rf

user@iar ~/aa
$ ls
op

user@iar ~/aa
$
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to use `ls -1` (number 1, not lowercase L) if you want to use *grep* on it's output.

But the main problem is, that you list the contents of a subdirectory, but the `rm` command is executed in the current directory.

For example see this directory tree (`.` and `..` entries omitted)

```
 a/
 a/x
 a/y
 a/z
```

Let's say you want to remove all from directory a except file `y` and use the command as you tried:

```
 $ ls -1 a | grep -v 'y'  | xargs rm -rf
```

`ls -1 a` gives:

```
 x
 y
 z
```

*grep* filters out the line with `y`:

```
 x
 z
```

so xargs excutes the following command:

```
 rm x z
```

But it executes the command in the top-level directory and sees only directory `a`, not the files `x` and `z`.

In order to make it work, you need the path of the files - easily achieved by applying a minor change to the *ls* command. Also we refine the grep pattern a bit:

```
 ls -1d a/* | grep -v '/y$'  | xargs rm -rf
```

So this time ls produces the following output:

```
 a/x
 a/y
 a/z
```

and the final command executed would be `rm -rf a/x a/z`

So now let's go back to your command line and apply the discussed changes:

```
 $ ls -1d domain.com/wp-content/themes/* | grep -v -E '/twentyeleven$|/index.php$'  | xargs rm -rf
```

**One last note:** Using `xargs rm -rf` is always venturesome (although sometimes neccessary) - be sure to check the output of the grep command first!

Comment: interesting.. though regarding the need to do -1, and I see -1 makes sense if | grep, but it works without it too.  If I do $ls<ENTER> it lists 5 files: er  op  qw  ty  ui   It lists them on one line.   And if I do $ls | od -c  I actually see \n in between each of them.  Infact ls -1 | od -c looks like it dumps the same output as ls | od -c   Just the \n is interpreted as new line in the case of ls -1 , but \n is still there with ls without -1.

Comment: @barlop: But one should not assume that this is true in every environment - whereas 'ls -1' is a standard option with a standard outcome (one file per line).

Comment: well, maybe ls including \n is standard on all *nix systems, I don't know, and if it is, then -1 is completely unnecessary! I see a thing worth noting about your method, is with globbing which you've used, it introduces something which isn't standard, some systems may be set to include . and .. (dot and dotdot)  some may not, which I suppose then get expanded like (dotdot colon) ..: then the files there.  And if (dotdot).. were to go literally to rm -rf , I guess it wouldn't but if it did then it's dangerous and not very portable to some systems!

Comment: Globbing files starting with a dot would be non-standard, too ;-)

Comment: yes i'm all for the consideration of catering to non-standard. But in the case of ls without -1, I don't know if there are *nix systems where the output doesn't have a \n.  Whereas in the case of globbing, I know for example bash has an option to make globbing include . and .. that's my point, and the distinction there. Also (and i'm not relying on this, but just as a side thing) it's quite a possibility that it's default to do so in some shells 'cos I vaguely recall possibly seeing a shell script demonstrating that.